# SQL Server: Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type bigint

Tags: sql-server

Here's the sequence of my query:

```
SELECT
      CASE
         WHEN ((BarCode IS NOT NULL) AND (ExternelBarCode IS NULL)) THEN BarCode
         WHEN ((BarCode IS NULL) AND (ExternelBarCode IS NOT NULL)) THEN CAST(ExternelBarCode AS bigint)
         ELSE ExternelBarCode -- When both exist
      END AS TicketBarCode
...
```

When I run it, I've got the following message:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type bigint.

The column `BarCode` is of type `bigint`, and column `ExternelBarCode` is of type `varchar(250)`.

```
BarCode = 178625624324,
ExternelBarCode = 2015591149641227565492
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: try float/decimal(6,2) and cast else part as well

Comment: What data is it trying to convert from `ExternelBarCode`?

Comment: Try to use as said by @Szymon

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The value 2,015,591,149,641,227,565,492 is greater than the maximum value allowed in `bigint` 2^63-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807) so the conversion is not possible.

If you need to return a numeric value, you can cast it to `decimal(38,0)`

```
SELECT
      CASE
         WHEN ((BarCode IS NOT NULL) AND (ExternelBarCode IS NULL)) THEN CAST(BarCode as decimal(38,0))
         WHEN ((BarCode IS NULL) AND (ExternelBarCode IS NOT NULL)) THEN CAST(ExternelBarCode AS decimal(38,0))
         ELSE cast(ExternelBarCode as decimal(38,0)) -- When both exist
      END AS TicketBarCode
```