# SQL Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type bigint

Tags: sql

I am trying to insert a number in sql table but I am stuck with this error. It would be great if anyone can help solve this

I created a table

```
CREATE TABLE BulkInsert
(
e bigint ,
N bigint
)

INSERT INTO BulkInsert
VALUES (11088915669531756490937241533141381079, 4);
```

But when I insert values in his table i get this error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type bigint.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: check this :http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51536/datatype-bigger-than-bigint

Comment: The value **11088915669531756490937241533141381079** is greater than the maximum value allowed in bigint **2^63-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807)**.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20674058/sql-server-arithmetic-overflow-error-converting-expression-to-data-type-bigint

Comment: that issue was solved.. thank you so much. I used float in place of big int colum type